# Geocoder.getFromLocation throws Exception

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geocoder.getFromLocation throws IOException on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator)

I am using Google api 7, Android2.1 emulator

I am trying to do reverse geocoding and I get:

03-07 16:19:42.661: WARN/System.err(261): java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server

on that line:

```
      List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
```

any idea?

thanks,
ray.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472313/android-reverse-geocoding-getfromlocation

Comment: [try this will sure helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173488/1151312)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that when you call that method, it fires off an API call to Google Maps' servers - it isn't doing it on the device. I suspect this is an error you will see sometimes, because the method is not managing to get a meaningful response from the Google Maps API. I've used this method and I occasionally see that error, but I usually put the method into a loop of 10 retries, and quietly ignore the occasional error. If it's happening every time you call the method, there's something odd happening

Comment: what might this odd something be? this just started happening on 2 galaxy nexus phones i'm testing but works fine on a froyo emulator....

Comment: I think Google is blocking IP!

Comment: I agree with @MuhammadBabar

Comment: @MuhammadBabar  u resolved ?

Comment: @ErumHannan Unfortunately if google blocks ip or there server doesn't respond this is something out of our control.