# how to make navigation with 3-axis accelerometer and 3-axis gyroscope and gps

Tags: algorithm, gps, sensors

as the title stated, I want to make Dead Reckoning with accelerometer and gyroscope. The accelerometer could apply with linear accleration and then used to get velocity by one time integration or get runing distance in the gap of sample time by twice integration. and also I could get changed angle by integration of gyroscope output value. so on the condition of initial position, I can get new postion by DR with distance and angle.

thought is perfect but fact is not so simple. acceleromter and gyroscope is unstable and always affected by temperature or unaligned axis direction. I have know there is one popular method called kalman filter to combined this sensors with gps to protect navigation from noise of output, but I think it's out of my comptent by now.

firstly, I want to know how to remove gravity force which is mixed with real accelerometer ouput?
sencond, how to correct gyroscope error?
the last, how to realize kalman filter with accelerometer, gyroscope and gps?

any suggestion is good to me, if you can give some code that's best of all!
thank you

[edit @2013/12/12]:
I have given up using accelemeter for calculating velocity and distance due to it's big drift. And also the error can become more and more under the influence of double integration. But there is a lucky thing that this work for a car in tis case. so I prefer to select receiving velocity from CAN, it was proven to be more exactly than accelerometer. By now a solution about velocity has been resolved, but the other question is still not sure in my opinion. expect more nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764828/2521214

**And read the whole thing !!!**

- including the comments
- and view also this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k ...
- video link is from AlexWien answer in the same thread