# What is the difference between TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensors?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I think `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` shows devices acceleration. However, I can't understand when I should use `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`?
I need to calculate the speed of moving the device. Which sensor is proper for this application?

Also, I read that `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` uses accelerometer and orientation to know where is directed the gravity and then subs.

How is this possible? How Android find out about orientation of device and subtract it?

Answer (score 9):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` is the same as `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` minus gravity: `acceleration = gravity + linear-acceleration`. So with `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` you can't detect device orientation because it doesn't provide gravity data.

*Acceleration* is the second derivative from object *location*, speed (*velocity*) is the first derivative. It means that you can calculate relative change in velocity from acceleration, but you can't know from it what exact values of velocity the change is applied to, in general case. For example you can't say if the phone stands on a table in room or in a constantly moving car, in both cases the acceleration may be zero.

Games use accelerometer input to track user's feedback, since it doesn't matter for games if user sits in a moving car or home at a table, acceleration just fits that purpose perfectly (filtering out the speed data). If you really need speed then you should use other sensors, such as **GPS**.

It may be a safe assumption that the phone initially has the same speed as the user, so you can calculate speed of phone when user throws it away, relative to the user, but that's all.

Comment: I think it's possible to calculate

Comment: Sure it's possible if you assume that phone's initial speed is zero. It depends on your use case.

Comment: I need velocity and displacement for a some application which the device could not access to GPS. Also the GPS is not accurate enough . Sometimes it gives accuracy more than 20 meter.
It's possible to calculate velocity using acceleration, however I don't know which sensor gives velocity and displacement properly.

Comment: AFAIK `Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE` should be used for such cases to get acceptable precision, but usually it is not present in mainstream Android devices. You may try to calculate velocity from acceleration if assume that car's velocity is zero at some point in time (when can starts moving). I have no idea what precision you'll get, it's interesting for me too

Comment: I consider the initial velocity as zero. By the way, I don't have TYPE_GYROSCOPE.

Comment: I think you already know formula to calculate velocity, like this: http://www.ajdesigner.com/constantacceleration/cavelocity.php You need to calculate an integral

Comment: Did you mean to say TYPE_ACCELEROMETER instead of TYPE_ACCELERATION?