# Spacecraft Dynamics 3D Graphics How to?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I want to render 3d objects going around earth.
3D objects would be satellites or space-crafts.
I would like also to render vectors from 3D objects for velocity, acceleration etc.
I am familiar with C++ and Java.
What would I need to know to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need basic math stuff for this like:

- vector math
- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Then also some basic **gfx** knowledge

- [simple graphics pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214)
- lighting,shading,[normal shading & bump mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214)...
- **gfx** api (**OpenGL,DirectX,GDI,...**)
- 3D mesh loading and rendering

And finally physics

- [Newton - D'ALembert physics for non relativistic speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764828/2521214)
- [realistic n-body solar system simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214)