# Service not Available - Geocoder Android

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I have a little problem with the geocoder to get latitude and lontitude from an address :

This is my code:

```
for (Garage g : XMLGarage) {
List<Address> address;
address = coder.getFromLocationName(
g.getAddress(), 5);
if (address != null) {
Address location = address.get(0);  
g.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
g.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
...
```

The error is :

```
08-18 14:28:56.026: WARN/System.err(359): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
08-18 14:28:56.026: WARN/System.err(359):     at 
android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
08-18 14:28:56.026: WARN/System.err(359):     at 
com.amt.android.garage.Garage.postData(Garage.java:269)
08-18 14:28:56.026: WARN/System.err(359):     at
com.amt.android.garage.GarageForm$2.onClick(GarageForm.java:86)
08-18 14:28:56.026: WARN/System.err(359):     at  
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-18 14:28:56.026: WARN/System.err(359):     at
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at  
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-18 14:28:56.036: WARN/System.err(359):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-18 14:28:56.046: WARN/System.err(359):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-18 14:28:56.046: WARN/System.err(359):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native    
Method)
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that even though this question is marked as a duplicate (which is correct), the top answer given on this question is a valid, possible solution that the other question does not offer.

Comment: Please reboot your device first, it might be enough to fix your problem.

Answer (score 100):

There is a problem recently with android devices and the geocoder not working:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

A reboot seems to fix the issue

Comment: suggesting a reboot is a terrible solution. Even more terrible of a solution when it's the correct one.  Worked for me.

Comment: We had this on 4 devices with different android versions. Have never seen this issue afterwards. (probably related to google play services update)

Comment: Wowwww!!!

Work for me too...

Next, how it work without 'Reboot' device?

Comment: Had this problem with 2 tablets.  Upgraded with Google play services and Geocoder did not work.  Reboot fixxed the issue.  Come on google...

Comment: Rebooting the device works... it must be an Android Bug

Comment: Incredible! Rebooting the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: rebooting fix the issue, but the problems comes back after a while. Can anyone help?

Comment: OK.. I just try to edit the post but my edit was rejected. I just want to share my experience: rebooting fix the problem just.. temporary. The bug comes back again. As an alternative, one can use Google Map API. I made a full working example availalbe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272918/service-not-available-in-geocoder/15853124#15853124

Comment: Yup solved. But why it happens? I mean it can directly impact on application and indirectly on android developer. Even it is the Android bug :(

Comment: For avoiding the reboot and solving the "Service not available" **Geocoder problem** you need to **set the Project Build Target to API 16**.  
In Eclipse: Right Click Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Android -> Project Build Target.

Comment: lol strangely worked for me :)

Comment: i think this is a silly solution, but it's worked!

Comment: I should be amazed that in 2016 I still see this problem on devices...

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier 2017 here... it can still happen with an API 25 target

Answer (score 13):

You will get this error occasionally if the GeoCoding provider fails and is unable to geocode your location.

See these relevant posts:

[Geocoder.getFromLocation throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222164/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-exception)

[Geocoder.getFromLocation throws IOException on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator)

If this is not the case, make sure you have the Internet permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Service not Available - Geocoder Android when i get this error in some cooked roms i wrote this library i hope could be useful. https://github.com/dnocode/gapis

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Location first. Like below

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 1, this);
```

refer to [***here***](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/42.html).