# Android: No location updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER on ICS

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

There are similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747543/locationlistener-of-network-provider-is-enabled-but-onlocationchanged-is-never) on this issue. It seems to be related to some devices running ICS and above that after a while (device entering "sleep mode"-if there is one?) there are no location updates from the NETWORK_PROVIDER any more even though Network provider is enabled. The GPS_PROVIDER still works just fine in open air. Have tried to toggle Wifi and such, but the only thing that seems to help is to reboot the device. Must be a solution for this?

Comment: Could you be able to fix this problem. Can you tell us how? thnks

Comment: No progress unfortunately. Seems it happens when the device has been left in standby a day or two. As said, only a shutdown/restart seems to help. (Google maps always works as stated in other posts)

Comment: Hmm, I have the same issue it seems. I use only `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and it just sometimes doesn't react on my test devices. Very frustrating. And I really need it. Any progress? Is it only 4.0.3? OR also 4.1+?

Comment: Seen it on 4.1+ as well. No progress...

Comment: Hi there, i've had this problem for ages, anyone made any progress?

Comment: Changed to Google Play Services which seems to work better, but then again I have problem with "Service not available" when using the Geocoder... only a reboot helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272918/service-not-available-in-geocoder?lq=1)