# Android: java.io.IOException: Service not Available while Android Geocoder.getFromLocation()

Tags: android, google-maps

I have problem with call:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> data = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

throw Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Service not Available
W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
W/System.err:     at <path to my class>.getGeolocationName(GPSTracker.java:325)
```

Nexus 5
Android 7.1.1 from [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/orig-development/wip-aosp-nougat-nexus-5-t3446875)
Google apps (Gapps) installed from [here](http://opengapps.org/) from "Aroma" variant. Google Play, Google Services are installed automatically. I added Google Maps, Google package installer.

Restart the device not fix the issue, because issue is about missing package i thing.

**UPDATE**
If Geocoder is not available, i use e Geocoding API: [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853124/4244605)
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762815/4244605): "*The Geocoder is part of the Google API add-on that isn't part of the AOSP.*" Could i install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Android Geocoder throwing a "Service not Available" exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception)

Answer (score -3):

Rebooting the Device will solve the problem