# android java.io.IOException: Service not Available

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Description: *I am using `Google maps API V2`.I have implemented `Android Reverse Geocoding` at touched location.*

Problem: It throws exception on

```
 try {
     addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);}
 catch (IOException e)
     {
     e.printStackTrace();
     if(AppConstants.DEBUG)Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG," e.printStackTrace(): "+e.getMessage());
     }
```

I am receiving `latitude` and `longitude` values correct, but i can't understand why it throws `exception` and i have also done Google search but it couldn't help.

Can anybody please explain in details??

Comment: Please update your question with complete stacktrace. try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4762815/1329126 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109240/service-not-available-geocoder-android.

Comment: Are you running in emulator or in real device?

Comment: @Sankar V - thanks for quick reply... according to accepted answer mentioned in above link -- (any device that doesn't come with the Play Store, GMail apps etc… will also be missing the Geocoder back-end.)What it means??

Comment: @ Pratik -no i m using device. (any device that doesn't come with the Play Store, GMail apps etc… will also be missing the Geocoder back-end.)can you explain me What it means??

Comment: Its clear in that, if there is no Google apps like PlayStore, GMail in device while purchasing, the devices lacks Geocoder too

Comment: Sankar V- i m using Samsung Galaxy Note 800...!

Comment: @patelpratik we really need your logcat stacktrace to identify the exact problem. Before that try rebooting your device and try

Comment: @Sankar V-There is nothing special in stacktrace that's why i have post the 1 line that cause exception..i will reboot my device then i will tell u if it works..!thanks again.

Comment: @Sankar V-Thanx a lot Rebooting worked.post your answer so that i can accept it..!

Comment: Facing same issue.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As stated in this [Android issue 38009 - Geocoder throwing exception: IOException: Service not Available](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009) **Rebooting the Device will solve the problem**

Comment: but after some time it will again show error. Is there any good solution for that?

Comment: Restarted device solved the issue but what is the best way to avoid it?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda Nothing. The issue is still open in bug tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956130. May be you can go with the answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061612/1329126

Answer (score 16):

**If you don't want to reboot the device use this**

```
     public  JSONObject getLocationFormGoogle(String placesName) {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +placesName+"&ka&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

public  LatLng getLatLng(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    Double lon = new Double(0);
    Double lat = new Double(0);

    try {

        lon = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new LatLng(lat,lon);

}



LatLng Source =getLatLng(getLocationFormGoogle(placesName));
```

Comment: This is the other way round. The original question was about getting address from LatLng.

Comment: Is this google api has limited usage? If yes, how much request can we make a day?

Answer (score 10):

I modified @Ani solution to get city name from lat long parameters:

```
public static String getLocationCityName( double lat, double lon ){
    JSONObject result = getLocationFormGoogle(lat + "," + lon );
    return getCityAddress(result);
}

protected static JSONObject getLocationFormGoogle(String placesName) {

    String apiRequest = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + placesName; //+ "&ka&sensor=false"
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(apiRequest);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

protected static String getCityAddress( JSONObject result ){
    if( result.has("results") ){
        try {
            JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("results");
            if( array.length() > 0 ){
                JSONObject place = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray components = place.getJSONArray("address_components");
                for( int i = 0 ; i < components.length() ; i++ ){
                    JSONObject component = components.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray types = component.getJSONArray("types");
                    for( int j = 0 ; j < types.length() ; j ++ ){
                        if( types.getString(j).equals("locality") ){
                            return component.getString("long_name");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: ML.log(apiRequest)...what is ML here??

Comment: Logger interface. Forgot to remove it. #mybad