# Enable backend service for geocoder class

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am creating an android application which accepts longitude and latitude as an input, and returns address name using `Reverse Geocoding`.
When I check `Geocoder.isPresent()` it returns false, which means backend service is disabled for geocoding class.

How can i enable this service?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below 2 posts for possible solutions:

1, [why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109240/service-not-available-geocoder-android)

2, [service-not-available-geocoder-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109240/service-not-available-geocoder-android)