# Android GCM SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, exception, google-cloud-messaging, service-not-available

I was trying to set this example: 
https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client
up and running.

The GoogleAPI project has been successfully created, according to the guide: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

However, I have the following problem: on some devices I get SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE no matter what.

W/System.err: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
W/System.err: at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)

Some statistics:

- Nexus 7, android 4.2.2: GCM example works perfectly
- Nexus 4, android 4.2: GCM example works perfectly
- Nexus S, android 4.2.2: GCM example works perfectly
- Samsung Galaxy 3: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in 100% cases
- Samsung Galaxy, android 2.3.6: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in 100% cases
- Motorola Xoom, android 4.1.2: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in 100% cases
- HTC Desire HD, android 2.3: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in 100% cases

It's the same code, the same apk file, various google accounts. I tried to switch back to GCMRegistrar methods and they actually work. So the question is: are new GCM methods in sort of beta? How to make them work on other devices, not just 'pure' Google Android devices?

**Update:** In fact, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17721385/1741459)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it happened due to time syn with GCM. Please have a look at the time, if it is correct. If possible then reset.

Two more thing to check, if you are using a emulator then please make sure that you have the google api running on the emulator. and second gcm.jar is included on your project.

Comment: I followed the following tutorial to make gcm functional http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: SYNC was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

this is super stupid, but I have same error because I had "restrict app background data" option enabled for google services on my xperia)

Comment: I had the same issue! It worked perfectly fine with a wifi connection. But when I tried it with mobile data it didn't work! So it must be something with mobile data settings! So I've disabled "Google Services" 'Restrict background data' and now it works fine :D

Answer (score 1):

Check your phone has an active network connection. I had this issue and then i realized that my test device disconnected from the wifi :)