# Does GCM need a Phonenumber?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Hi i'm creating a GCM application

on my normal galaxy s4 it works, but on my dev phone (galaxy S1, 2.3.3, without sim, own google account) i keep getting this error

```
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
```

my register code

```
if (gcm == null) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
}
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

any hints why?

Comment: Does your galaxy S1, 2.3.3 has the latest update of Google Play Services. You the latest Play Store and its services for the GCM service to work properly. It might be the reason to your problem.

Comment: hm i can open the playstore and it doen't show anything to be updated, but the problem lasts

Comment: check in the settings of the playstore -> Auto-update apps -> Check if  auto update is on. Also check the build of Google Play Store , it should be at least 4.1.6

Comment: auto update is on, and version is 4.1.6 =/ but the workaround as mentioned below is working

Comment: You must also copy the gcm.jar to your libs folder in the project.
That workaround is actually what is necessary for the registration process.    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />      This actually receives the registration ID. So with this you cannot get the registration ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM does not need your phone no. It does not require you to have a sim installed in your device.

It requires internet connection, Google account setup in the phone, Google Play Store to be present and it should be linked with the same google account.

Comment: I guess you meant for this specific user who uses Android 2.3.3. In general terms, Android specifies: `It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.`

Answer (score 0):

ok found this

[GCM SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618982/gcm-service-not-available-on-android-2-2/17721385#17721385)

which means

```
gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

still fails, but somehow in the GcmBroadcastReceiver you will get the regid by event... i think i'll use this workaround