# Android GCM doesnt register device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Code:

```
String msg = "";
try {
    if (gcm == null) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging
        .getInstance(OrfografApplication.this);
    }
    String senderId = Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID;
    GCM_REGISTRATION_ID = gcm.register(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID);
    msg = "Device registered, registration id="
                    + GCM_REGISTRATION_ID;
    setRegistrationId(OrfografApplication.this,
                        GCM_REGISTRATION_ID);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.w(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
}
return msg;
```

Exception message `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

In logcat `: W/GCM(749): DIR: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_APP /data/data/com.google.android.gsf`

It worked fine, but stoped at 23 of august.

Comment: Ok, do the following things in order to help you solve your problem:
First, add your code!
Second, add your error message, this log-line does not help to understand your problem
Third, clarify your problem! What is the code supposed to do? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

See answers on [SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427635/service-not-available-gcm). There can be many reasons for the same. One of them could be that either device can't read the response or there was a 500/503 from the server. Apparently there is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=57699&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=57699#makechanges) also, which hasn't been resolved yet. See the details in the link above.