# GCM SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM in my android application and when I try to register the device with GCM (with the command `gcm.register(SENDER_ID)`) I get the SEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error, I tried what someone suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618982/gcm-service-not-available-on-android-2-2/17721385#17721385) (the accepted solution) and I did get the registration id.

Why is it like that?

Android manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appspot.smartgan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.appspot.smartgan" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service 
            android:name=".GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.appspot.smartgan.ChildActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_child" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

register method:

```
private void registerInBackground() {   
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String message = "";

            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                message = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                Log.d("SMARTGAN_PLAY", "register completed");

                // send registration id to the server
                sendRegistrationIdToServer();

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                message = "Error:" + e.getMessage();
            }
            return message;
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think issue is regarding allowed IP addresses mentioned in your Google API project. 
Please check details of the project and remove IP address if present under `restrict use to IP address`. I faced similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a Register ID it means you have registered the device successfully to the GCM.

**Edit:**
Here is a good tutorial for GCM: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

```
<receiver
        android:name="rockit.app.beardallstreetprimary.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="rockit.app.beardallstreetprimary" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true" />
```

My GCM is set up based on the Tutorial i linked above so if you read through that aswell it should work for you it looks like your not far off. I will say the Manifest is very picky and you need to ensure that you link your Packages fully.

Also you dont need the Register Intent

Comment: I know but when the `gcm.register()` yields an IOException

Comment: I really cant help you to much without seeing a copy of your code so i know exactly where your placing your register command. Ive edited my answer with a link to a tutorial that helped me to get mine to work. If you can edit your question with your code ill be able to help more.

Comment: the activity class in which the register function is called is very long so I can't add everything here, but I followed the sample project Google published [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) so you can see my code there it's the same.

Comment: Honestly mate we really cant help you unless we see some code we are just stabbing in the dark at the moment. i get the feeling it could be a manifest thing tbh all my problems stemmed from incorrectly setting up the receiver in the manifest.

Comment: I've added both the manifest and the registerInBackground function

Comment: Sorry for the wait in a reply it was christmas and i wasnt in my office ive updated my answer with an example of a manifest receiver code.