# GCM repeatedly gives SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE while registering

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm somewhat at my wits end here.  I had a working GCM monodroid client solution based on PushSharp.  This is now failing to register with the message:

```
handleRegistration: registrationId = , error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered =
```

I've tried downloading the unadulterated source from GitHub and simply changing the following:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]

namespace PushSharp.ClientSample.MonoForAndroid
{
//You must subclass this!
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission=GCMConstants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE }, Categories = new string[] { "test.tmt" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK }, Categories = new string[] { "test.tmt" })]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY }, Categories = new string[] { "test.tmt" })]
```

Along with changing the package name to "test.tmt" and setting the SENDER_IDS.   I've recreated the google project and am running out of ideas.  It's not the date time on the phone either.   I did do a lot of registering and deregistring on the same test phone - could that have caused google to block the phone?

I am using android version 2.3.6

I have tried this workaround [GCM SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618982/gcm-service-not-available-on-android-2-2/17721385#17721385) but get the error message "intent does not have a getExtras() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - for the benefit of anyone else who may reach this issue.  The problem was a combination of a cheap Motorola phone, android 2.3.6 and GMail! Android 2.3.6 requires a google account to function.  This had been set up as an email account and worked fine.  The phone's battery discharged fully and on re-charging it had dropped the GMail  account.

I hadn't realised this.  The oh so helpful message that was returned was not very helpful at all - being accurate and misleading.  On discovering that there was no GMail account re-installing it lead to instant success. Not sure if there is a moral to this story but you really *do* have to check everything.