# Android GCM - Exception thrown SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE when trying to register

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Google Cloud Messaging in my android app, but when I try to register the device to the GCM server (`gcm.register(senderIds)`) I get an error:

`IOException - SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`...

Any help?

Comment: which device are you using? Android O.S. / API level? Asked because of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618982/gcm-service-not-available-on-android-2-2

Comment: I am using a Xperia S running android version 4.1.2 Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've correctly followed the necessary steps ([Android GCM SDK Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)) to configure GCM in the manifest, getting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE is not uncommon, sometimes the service is not available.  You're app should periodically attempt to register with a back-off strategy.