# GeoCoder Service not Available

Tags: android, geocoding, google-play-services, android-location, google-geocoder

GeoCoder Service not Available

I'm using the `GeoCoder` to get an `AddressLocation`.
Unfortunately the  method fires an `IOException saying: "Service not Available"`.

[This StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation) explains what is going on because I tested it thoroughly (user permissions, build versions, restarts, GeoCoding API limits, etc.).

The `Google Play-Services` (or `LocationService`) that you can find in: Android Settings -> (Manage) Applications --> Running Process, has crashed or stopped. It restarts itself but forgets to bind the GeoCoderService to the NetworkLocator.

The "Solution" to this bug is to restart the Android phone, because on reboot the GeoCoderService is binded to the NetworkLocater.
Of course I do not find this a solution.

## QUESTION

My question is, how does the LocationService crash or get stopped in the first place?

What I did is force-stop the Google Play-Service by hand and some devices restarted the LocationService but some didn't.

**NOT WORKING** (did not restart LocationService)

- 4.0.3 Samsung Galaxy Note (GT-N7000)
- 4.0.4 Samsung Tablet GT-P7100
- 4.1.2 nexus S
- 4.1.2 Samsung Galaxy S III  (GT-I9300)

**WORKING** (did restart LocationService)

- 2.3.5 HTC Wildfired S
- 4.0.3 Acer A500
- 4.1.1 Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT-7100)
- 4.1.2 Samsung Galaxy S II (GT-I9105P)
- 4.2.2 Samsung Tablet GT-P7500
- 4.2.2 Nexus 7
- 4.3 Galaxy Nexus

Does anybody know what the reason is that the Google Play-service (LocationService) crashes or get's stopped after running a while?

I already escalated this issue to the b.Android.com and personally contacted Android developers.

I've seen that my issue has been discussed in other threads but did not pull any conclusion:

- [Android bugTracker issue 38009](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009)
- [StackOverFlow 7109240](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109240/service-not-available-geocoder-android)

Comment: It worked for me I hope the happens with you

[StackOverFlow Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation

Answer (score 3):

Restart device check again(i have face same issue.)

Answer (score 2):

Some devices do not have suport for Geocoder, so what you need to do is create your own geocoder.

Basicaly you need create a async task to request google for the address and treat the json response.

Using aquery, i do something like this:

```
public void asyncJson(String address){
        address = address.replace(" ", "+");

        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+ address +"&sensor=true";

        aq.ajax(url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {                        

                        if(json != null){

                                 //here you work with the response json
                                 JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");                               
                                Toast.makeText(context, results.getJSONObject(1).getString("formatted_address"));

                        }else{                                
                                //ajax error, show error code
                                Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
        });        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Samsung Galaxy S II with Android 4.1.2 to your **NOT WORKING** list. This is an annoying bug and a work-around is to access the GMaps API in a direct manner. From my point of view it happens when the user kills all apps with the build-in task manager to free resources/memory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, add below permissions to resolve it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restart the "Network Location" service on Manege Apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java).

Geocoder in Android SDK is implemented by device vendors, and some of them don't want to bother with it.

**UPD:** Google Maps Services are not intended to use in Android, so you can use [Mapbox Geocoder](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/geocoder/).