# Reverse Geocoding - Service Not available - Restart device not solving definitively - criticize my manual inverse geocoding

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoder, service-not-available

From times to times I meet the `Service Not Available` Exceptions in my application. Most of the time, there is no problem. But sometimes it happens. (The app is still under development)

Only way to solve it is to **restart the handset**. [Relevant Issue38009 on support forums](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009). But what I understand from the comments is that rebooting the device solve the issue **forever**.

**Is this correct?**
Because in my case, the bug can return (frequency: once or twice a month I think & I am full time on this app).

Is there **a way to restart the geocoder from inside the application**?

The only solution I have is to provide an alternative solution just in case to fetch "manually" the address like this below. Do you have any better?

```
    Dbg.d(TAG, "=== address_info FetchLocationTask - doInBackground");
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}).start();

    /**
     * Implementation of a second method in case of failure:
     * 
     */
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    String address = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
            "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+Double.toString(lat)+","+Double.toString(lng)+"&sensor=true&language="+Locale.getDefault().getCountry(), lat, lng);
    Dbg.d(TAG, "fetching path : "+ address);


    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(address);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    List<Address> retList = null;

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());


        retList = new ArrayList<Address>();


        if("OK".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonObject.getString("status"))){
            JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i=0;i<results.length();i++ ) {
                JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                String indiStr = result.getString("formatted_address");
                Address addr = new Address(Locale.ITALY);
                addr.setAddressLine(0, indiStr);
                Dbg.d(TAG, "adresse :"+addr.toString());
                retList.add(addr);
            }
        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Dbg.e(TAG, "Error calling Google geocode webservice.", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Dbg.e(TAG, "Error calling Google geocode webservice.", e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Dbg.e(TAG, "Error parsing Google geocode webservice response.", e);
    }

    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

    boolean found = false;

    if (retList.size() > 0) {

        Address a = retList.get(0);

        String name = a.getAddressLine(0);
        String city = a.getLocality();
        String postalCode = a.getPostalCode();
        String country = a.getCountryName();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            JsonUtils.setSringInJson(jObj, BookLocation.ADDRESS_NAME_KEY, name);
            found = true;
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(postalCode)) {
            JsonUtils.setSringInJson(jObj, BookLocation.ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE_KEY, postalCode);
            found = true;
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(city)) {
            JsonUtils.setSringInJson(jObj, BookLocation.ADDRESS_CITY_KEY, city);
            found = true;
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(country)) {
            JsonUtils.setSringInJson(jObj, BookLocation.ADDRESS_COUNTRY_KEY, country);
            found = true;
        }

    }
    mHandler.getLooper().quit();
    if (found) {
        return jObj;
    } else return null;
```

Comment: Your link should be pointing here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

From my reading of the issue, _no_, rebooting does not permanently solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the link from @mike states:  a fallback implementation using GeoCoder handler and asynctask class both needs to be synchronized - like if no service we can get the address from URL.
This is the only solution we can provide unfortunately @Poutrathor.

Refer here [Service not Available - Geocoder Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109240/service-not-available-geocoder-android)

Also we cannot force user to reboot but at least inform a solution about it.

Comment: Hello ! your link has failed, close it this way: [Service not Available - Geocoder Android](link)