# Can only obtain address using GeoCoder with WiFi, not mobile internet (LTE)

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, reverse-geocoding

When I run the "Location Address" sample found here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

The app only fetches the address when connected to WiFi. When I turn WiFi off and use LTE I see "Sorry, the service is not available."

I'm trying to transfer this code to my own project but I want this to work using mobile internet as well as WiFi.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

logcat following timeout:

```
09-28 21:05:40.219  16344-19027/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationaddress E/fetch-address-intent-service﹕ Sorry, the service is not available
java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server
        at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationaddress.FetchAddressIntentService.onHandleIntent(FetchAddressIntentService.java:92)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Can you post the logs when you try conncting with LTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get geocoder working using mobile internet so I resorted to using google maps api, which works over wifi and mobile internet. Here is my implementation:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +
                    latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=true");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.connect();

            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(conn.getInputStream()).toString();
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

            Log.d("json result", "Geocoder Status: " + jsonResponse.getString("status"));
            if("OK".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonResponse.getString("status"))) {
                JSONArray addressComponents = ((JSONArray)jsonResponse.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");
                for (int i = 0; i < addressComponents.length(); i++) {
                    String addressComponent = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) addressComponents.get(i)).get("types")).getString(0);
                    if (addressComponent.equals("locality")) {
                        locality = ((JSONObject) addressComponents.get(i)).getString("long_name");
                    }
                    if (addressComponent.equals("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                        admin1 = ((JSONObject) addressComponents.get(i)).getString("long_name");
                    }
                    if (addressComponent.equals("country")) {
                        countryCode = ((JSONObject) addressComponents.get(i)).getString("short_name");
                    }
                }
                Log.d("json result", locality + "." + admin1 + "." + countryCode);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String rLine = "";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            answer.append(rLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(),
                "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some posts from 2014 indicate Geocoder may not work as well with LTE. See for example
[Geocoder "Timed out waiting for response from server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824408/geocoder-timed-out-waiting-for-response-from-server)

The suggestion was to use the web API instead. See [Google Geocoder service is unavaliable (Coordinates to address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059894/google-geocoder-service-is-unavaliable-coordinates-to-address/19061688#19061688)

Please report back with any success you have. I'm using geocoder too but so far, just on Wifi (and it works)

Comment: I'm going to move onto other things before I try fixing this with the example you provided. I will come back to it and post when I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: I eventually resorted to using google maps api through http url connection. See my answer below.