# Android Geocoder class change response timeout.

Tags: android, timeout, location

I'm developing an application that rely on the web to get some location informations. Everything is working fine, except that sometimes the Internet is slow, and the Geocoder class timeout before sending the results.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
```

I tried investigating geocoder's methods, but timeout is not there.
How can i fix this?

---

PS: `addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);` is inside asynctask's doInBackground().

Thanks.

Comment: This is the error thrown : java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server
at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
04-10 19:15:58.530: W/System.err(9387):  at ReverseGeocodingTask.doInBackground(ReverseGeocodingTask.java:39)

Comment: Maybe try something like the following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638067/geocoder-getfromlocation-function-throws-timed-out-waiting-for-server-response

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found that before but the getFromLocation function takes string address as arguments and not longitude and latitude. Is there any solution??

Comment: in the example replace http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng= See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests for more information.