# Geocoder suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, geocode

I am using Geocoder to get the lat and long in my android application. It was working fine some while back but now it just stopped working. I didn't change the code. Why this happned?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    List<Address> addressList= null;
            if(str != null || str.equals("") ){
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(str, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                //LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("location", str);
                i.putExtra("latitude", address.getLatitude());
                i.putExtra("longitude", address.getLongitude());
                startActivity(i);
            }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Why someone is down voting? At least tell us where we are going wrong?

Comment: This call requires an Internet connection.  Do you have an Internet connection when it's not working?

Comment: Ya I have Internet connection. It was working fine 7-8 hrs ago.

Comment: Service not available perhaps? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109240/service-not-available-geocoder-android   Check your log output....

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving `IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server` error? Because I've already seen other posts where it is mentioned that `Geocoder` isn't functioning properly, even though it did earlier (a few hours/days ago). I went to the public ticket - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153 - that was made when this happened last January, and it seems there are others who are experiencing this. You did mention you didn't modify anything in the code, right?