# java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server

Tags: android

Actually Im finding the latitude and longitude for the address such as(hard rock cafe, toit etc) but max time getting **`java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server`**. So whenever i'm getting this exception so using google api but both responses are different. If I use google api for some places its returning center of the Bangalore.

```
 private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.serachingForParking));
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {
        try {
            if (Dialog.isShowing()) {
                Dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                //
                } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

                    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(0);

                    latlang = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),
                            address.getLongitude());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geocoder.getFromLocation throws Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222164/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-exception)