# Couldn't achieve Reverse Geocoding

Tags: android

I am working on GPS system for android. I am able to find the latitude and longitude of my current position, but when I try to convert my latitude and longitude into Physical address my code doesn't work. I have tried several possibilities. I have posted my code here.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
try {

        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        System.out.println(""+latitude);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {

        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
        }
        addressString = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        } else {
        latLongString = "No location found";
        }
        myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
        latLongString + "\n" + addressString);
        }
```

My problem is, I couldn't get any value in the `List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);`
. It returns a empty list only. 
Could anyone tell me what the problem is and how to sort it out...

Comment: Sure that your latitude/longitude are correct values? What happens if you give hardcoded values where you are sure that there is a corresponding address?

Comment: @MarvinLabs I tried hardcoded values too.. But still the list is empty.

Comment: You may already know this, but have you added the INTERNET permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: More info and bugs there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator/5206936#5206936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses;
addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);        
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
{
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
         sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append(",");
}
```

This would get a location. But sometimes an exception comes as `"Unable to parse the response from server"`. You need to handle the exception.Also check for the `INTERNET permission` in the manifest.

Comment: Hi there.. I have tried this already. I was actually asking for a different approach if exists.

Comment: then u can probably call a google webservice and handle the result

Comment: webservice like this....  http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=lattitude,longitude&output=csv&sensor=false

Comment: Then handle the result. String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q="+lattitude+","+longitude+"&output=csv&sensor=false";
Uri.parse(url);
HttpClient mClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
try 
{
HttpResponse res = mClient.execute(get);
String msg = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity());
String[] addressInfo = msg.split(",");
msg ="";
for (int i = 2; i < addressInfo.length; i++) {
 msg = msg+addressInfo[i];
}
msg = "Location: " + msg ; The string msg here will contain the address.

Comment: Great idea.. Thanks there.. I will try to use it and will let know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If the GeoCoder returns an empty list, you need to check if you have a proper GeoCoder implementation available on the device (emulator or real phone).

This can be done using the isPresent() method on the Geocoder object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Also, when running on an emulator, make sure your AVD image is setup with the Google APIs.