# Getting geolocation from a street direction

Tags: android, geolocation, maps

My users can create events with geolocation. However, prompting them to introduce a correct geolocation is far from optimal, and asking them to point in a map and then converting the pressed geolocation is a very inaccurate approach.

Is there any free service that takes a string and returns a geolocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) can be used to convert street addresses to geolocations and vice-versa (that is called "reverse geocoding".

Comment: "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform." So basically it says I need to implement my own backend service? Not very useful.

Comment: No, you don't have to implement your own service. The geolocation services are not included in "core android". They are a available in a Google external library. Download the Google APIs for your Android platform. There are location services included with that. It uses the Google maps API. See https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator/9173488#9173488 and many other related posts on StackOverflow