# How to find location from  where image is captured?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm working on Android application. In this, I need that when I capture image or selects from gallery for uploading, it should show current location like city etc. I've tried using GPS but when I run it on Android Emulator, it shows Latitude and Longitude with 0 ,0 . Any help will be appreciated. What should I do for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not fetch GPS in emulator.But there is a work around for that

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Connect to your emulator.Like shown above and then

```
geo fix -23.234334 32.234344 4392
```

First two are longitude and latitude values and the last one is altitude in meters.

Now from there you can call from GeoCoder
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

```
 public List<Address> getFromLocation (double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)
```

It will return a list of Address that has a method getLocality

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    Log.i("address",""+addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Try with various values and check!

Comment: Thanks Amit .But Actully i want to get location name like Jaipur,Delhi etc.

Comment: i used it .when i am printing toast notification it showing service not available.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your manifest and check internet availability

Comment: also check
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can not fetch GPS in emulator. Emulator is not an real device. You can use .gpx files which contains lal-lon details. You need to upload this file from DDMS when your program is running, so you can fetch dummy GPS Co-ordinates in emulator.

You can find sample .gpx from [google](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=.gpx+file+download&oq=.gpx&gs_l=hp.3.3.0l4.1840.4129.0.7890.8.7.1.0.0.1.1618.4676.4-2j2j1j0j1.6.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2DdFi9KiQNc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9c515f559cf0b04c&biw=1600&bih=787)

Comment: Yes. I want to Get Location Name Like Jaipur,Delhi etc.