# android geolocation not returning address and locality

Tags: android, geolocation

In my app Location Service is not returning address and locality for my current lat-long

```
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10); 
    for (Address address : addresses) {
       textOut.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
```

The above code keeps on running forever while when I just want to display lat-long it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the following uses-permissions added to your manifest xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

The Geocoder class has a static method isPresent(). Does this return true on your device?

Failing that, it may be simply be that no matches were found. See [SDK doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) . Have you tried with different locations?

Alternatively, you can call the Google Geocode API directly. See the docs here: [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: I have those permissions in place as the location manager is giving me correct lat-long

Comment: I updated the answer above. Have you tried using different lat-longs? And if so, is the result always the same?

Comment: yes I have tried with lat-long given in developer's manual i.e. for Amphitheatre location.

Eclipse tells me

The method isPresent() is undefined for the type Geocoder

Comment: Is this the example you are referring to http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html
Also, are you using a device or the emulator?

Comment: I am on the emulator and I am following the book _Learning Android, Second Edition by Marko Gargenta and Masumi Nakamura_

Comment: I suspect that I may be Geocoder.getFromLocation() is not supported on the emulator you are using. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator

Comment: you are right its working on physical device. Emulator was the issue. But I didn't get why emulator was not working? its ok. **Thanks For All Your Help :)**

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I’ve generally found the Geocoder implementation quite fragmented, works on certain devices but not others. Because of which I tend to use Googles Geocode API in any production code.