# Reverse Geocode is not showing the address

Tags: android, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

This code shows like couldn't get the address. 
Is there any possibility to get the address from latitude and longitude?
what would be the reason?

I have been trying many similar codes but i couldn't. I tried the following sites solution too. yet nothin worked.

http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-using-gps-network-provider/

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/11/tutorial-63-implement-reverse-geocoding-in-android/

Code is here

```
package com.example.androidreversegeocode;``

import java.io.IOException;   
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Locale;  
import android.location.Address;    
import android.location.Geocoder;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;    
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button myLocation;
private TextView myAddress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myLocation= (Button) findViewById(R.id.location);
    myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

    myLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getMyLocationAddress();
        }
    });

}

public void getMyLocationAddress() {

    Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

    try {

          //Place your latitude and longitude
          List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(13.05612948,80.27297011, 1);

          if(addresses != null) {

              Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
              StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();

              for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
              }

              myAddress.setText("I am at: " +strAddress.toString());

          }

          else
              myAddress.setText("No location found..!");

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not get address..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the output of your stack trace from the IOException thrown?

Comment: I cant get u. I'm a beginner. I know that catch block has executed and so the couldnt get address msg came.

Comment: If you're getting the message `Could not get address..!`, it means that an exception is being thrown and caught by `catch (IOException e)`. `e.printStackTrace();` should be outputting to a debug window somewhere that you should be able to view and see what is causing the geocoder to fail.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know why the geocoder class is throwing an exception in your situation. You'll need to find out what the contents of the exception are. Try find out where in your IDE the debug window is.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Is this exception is due to my location? But i got lattiude and longitude values correctly.

Comment: Try check your console view: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-console_view.htm. It's also possible that you're encountering this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator

Comment: Sir i tried debugging the code in my real device. i got the address correctly. what has happened actually now?

Comment: If it works on your device but not on your emulator then it is probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator

Comment: no sir. from first it didnt work on my device oly. ! now come how suddenly worked i dont know.!

Comment: The same code didnt work when i ran it. but worked when i debugged it.!

Comment: Well if it's working now then something must have changed. Maybe add some logging to your application: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Comment: Thanku sir. Hope it ll work well hereon too

Comment: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))

Comment: Getting this exception when i debugged again