# Why result size of getFromLocation() is 0 ? How to get address from geopoint ? - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask, reverse-geocoding

I want to return a string array from Async class back to the activity that is calling this asynchronous class that is job is to do the reverse geocoding.

---

So, from my activity I call the constructor of the class like this:

```
Double[] lat_long = new Double[] { Double.parseDouble(map_lat), Double.parseDouble(map_long) };

            ReverseGeocodingTask reverseGeocoding = new ReverseGeocodingTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            reverseGeocoding.execute(lat_long);
```

---

And this is the code of the class:

```
class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, List<String>> {

    public static List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<String>();

    Context mContext;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Double... params) {
        Geocoder gc= new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> addrList = null;

        double latitude = params[0].doubleValue();
        double longitude = params[1].doubleValue();

        Log.d("LATLONG", latitude + ":" + longitude);

        try {
            addrList = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            if (addrList.size() > 0) {
                //format location info
                Address address = addrList.get(0);

                LIST.add(address.getLocality());
                LIST.add(address.getSubAdminArea());
                LIST.add(address.getCountryName());

                Log.d("LIST", LIST.get(0));
            }
            else{
                Log.d("addrList SIZE", "=0");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return LIST;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("ON POST", result.get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the logcat:

```
02-28 19:20:04.323  12275-14109/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/LATLONG﹕ 34.681377999999995:33.039339
02-28 19:20:05.434  12275-14109/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/addrList SIZE﹕ =0
```

---

I get correctly the latitude and longitude point as you can see from the `Log.d()`, BUT `getFromLocation.size()` is always 0.

Comment: addrList = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5);

Comment: The size still equals to 0 @Softcoder .

Comment: Are you testing it on a device with up-to-date Google Play Services?

Comment: How can I check that; Note that in another AsyncTask i am using fine the geocoding method with `getFromLocationName()`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with your `GeoCoder` service. If you're backend service for the device is not present or has other problems, you will get this response.

use `isPresent` to check if an implementation is present.

Also, see this post here:

[Geocoder.getFromLocation throws IOException on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205650/geocoder-getfromlocation-throws-ioexception-on-android-emulator)

And the docs mention that you need a backend service:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: I added this check: `if (gc.isPresent()) {` and the geocoder is present indeed. Also, I am using geocoder and `GetFromlocationName()` instead of `GetFromLocation()` in another activity and another AsyncTask  and it's working fine. But that whole solution about `GetFomLocationName()` was using also `HttpPost` etc. I just didn't know how to change that class to make it work for `GetFromLocation()` too.